# Growing animation that’s super specific and weird

Tags: animation, shape-keys

[image: I quickly drew out a rough idea of the growth. It's horrid but it's honestly the best I can do.]So I have this model of an Apple that I’m going to (hopefully) use in a game. For movement I’d like to have an arm on its top. I’d like to have an animation where the arm grows out of the top. I know about shape keys and I didn’t think they would work since you can’t add vertices in them. If anyone has any ideas on how I would accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you already asked the question I think. Not sure about why not shapekeys? You could also scale the bones in Pose mode...

Comment: I’m still super confused on how I would use shape keys to do that. Is there any way you could explain a little more?

Comment: the default cube has 8 vertices, if you subdivide it a few times it has many more vertices but it will render exactly the same. Create your arm fully grown with a many vertices as you need and set it as a Shape Key. Then move all the vertices so that the result is the un-grown arm. Even if the the un-grown arm has significantly less detail it will still have the correct number of vertices and can be used as a Shape Key.

Comment: Or use two objects, apple and arm.  Have a hole in apple where arm grows out. Shapekey on hole to open close.

Comment: @WhimbleThimble you know, an apple with a growing arm on it top "for movement" is not a very understandable concept... please add some more detail, maybe a screenshot with some marks (eg: using blender's grease pencil) showing a bit what you wish to achieve. As rob said above, shape keys could help you but you must have all needed geometry from the start, since shape keys can only _transform_ existing geometry, not add or remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with your arm growing on the top of your apple, but here are the two solutions I was thinking about (quickly made):

- Either you do it with Shapekeys, building a progressive growth with at least two positions. To make this you have to begin with a flat apple in the first shapekey, then add the rest in the following shapekeys.
- Or you do it with an armature and just scale up/scale down the bones of your arm

[image]